# Hyperledger Fabric Node.js Sdk getGenesisBlock error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been toying with hyperledger fabric Node.js sdk for a few hours. I have all the docker containers running. The js file and network configuration files are as shown below.

> file.js

```
'use strict';
const Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
const Fabric_CA_Client = require('fabric-ca-client');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');

let fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

fabric_client.loadFromConfig('network.yaml');
fabric_client.loadFromConfig('org_store.yaml');

let channel = fabric_client.getChannel('mychannel');
let peers = channel.getPeers();
let oderer_node = channel.getOrderers();
let tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID(true);
let request = {
    txId: tx_id,
    orderer: 'orderer.example.com'
}

channel.getGenesisBlock(request).then((value)=>{
    console.log(value);
})
```

> network.yaml

```
   name: "Network"
version: "1.0"

channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer1.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: false
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: false
      peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer1.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: false
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: false

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca0
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/e08c05b9ddf8b559e4c54c7aa9a2f61b08fc2a24adf002b2a4964cf92435168f_sk
    signedCert:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem

  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca1
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/6bab3a1bc4eddfaf82e28c1d3ee61778e25fd7e03e16fddc6e26637c0fa44be1_sk
    signedCert:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    name: orderer.example.com
    url: grpcs://localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      grpc-max-send-message-length: 15
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
    eventUrl: grpcs://localhost:7053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:8051
    eventUrl: grpcs://localhost:8053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:9051
    eventUrl: grpcs://localhost:9053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:10051
    eventUrl: grpcs://localhost:10053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  ca0:
    url: https://localhost:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca-org1

  ca1:
    url: https://localhost:8054
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca-org2
```

> org_store.yaml

```
name: "Org Client" version: "1.0"

client:   organization: Org1   credentialStore:
    path: "hfc-kvs/org1"
    cryptoStore:
      path: "hfc-cvs/org1"
```

I'm using Hyperledger fabric images of version 1.0.5. All the network and crypt config files have been created. The docker version is :`Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`. Docker-compose version: docker-`compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7`.

Here is the error I am getting when i run the js file :

```
error: [Orderer.js]: sendDeliver - rejecting - status:NOT_FOUND
(node:15180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/media/javauser/Data/kevin/HyperLedger/fabric-samples/first-network_with_nodejs/node_modules/fabric-client
/lib/Orderer.js:234:22)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at readCallback (/media/javauser/Data/kevin/HyperLedger/fabric-samples/first-network_with_nodejs/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:313:14)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you create and join the peers to the channel?

Comment: @jworthington Hey thanks for responding. To join the peers to the channel, I need a genesis block and when i try to get one, I get an error like in the question.

Comment: Did you create the genesis block? You should be able to use configtxgen  -inspectBlock genesis.block to view details of it. The genesis block has to be created, of course, but you don't get it to create and join a channel.